# Delphi XE5 Android development. How to set CPU Architecture (ABI) in APK

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I wondered Delphi XE5 by making Android APK files sets supported CPU Architecture (ABI) to "armeabi", but in documentation we see 
"RAD Studio supports development on **ARMv7** devices that run the following versions of the Android operating system... ". Them I making APK by XE5 and trying to publish is to Google Play, its says APK CPU Architecture is **armeabi** thats means that my APK able to run on ARM6 and lower CPU devices, but it is not. Can I manually set CPU architecture to "armeabi-v7a" to limit number of supported devices? There is no such options in XE5 project settings.  Noting about that in AndrondManifest documentation too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi already uses `armeabi-v7a` and does not support ARMv6. That being said, there is a known `armeabi`/`armeabi-v7a` incompatibility that prevents Delphi APKs from loading correctly on some devices:

[QC #119786](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119786)

Comment: Yes, I now that. But Google play think I am uploading  "armeabi" supported APK? I do not understand... it must be some settings to determine what CPU architecture I want to use to run APK. This setting have to limit supported devices in google play/

Comment: When I run Delphi APKs through Blackberry's online [Android repackaging tool](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/) (they always fail validation due to Delphi's use of JNI), it reports that they use `armeabi-v7a` instead. So I don't think it is a setting of the APK. Somehow Google is looking at something differently than Blackberry is. Maybe the directory structure of the APK, maybe some flag somewhere, I don't know. Contact Google and find out what the actual criteria is they are looking for.

Comment: Well, I found the source of the problem. Google play make decision about CPU architecture by directory structure in APK. Delphi by making APK put **armeabi** subdirectory  in Lib directory. When I changed then directory to **armeabi-v7a** in APK (WinRAR) and uploaded it to Google Play. It says you APK is armeabi-v7a achitecture. This part of problem is solved )). BUT it is still problem is my changed APK naturally do not work on device.
 I thought

Comment: ... I thought I can change deployment remote path values to urge Delphi make right directory, but it is not helped. Is says cant copy to armeabi directory. Any Help?